# Joining a python list to one pretty multi line string

Tags: python, list, join

I would like a multi-line string that is essentially a "pretty-printing" of a list object, I know I can kind of use `str.join(iterable)` for this, but the problem is that joining with `"\n- "` for example would give:

```
a
- b
- c
```

But I would like it to look like this instead:

```
- a
- b
- c
```

I understand why this is happening, I'm just wondering if there's a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do. I don't want to use a for loop with one print per item, because I'm trying to create one single multi line string object.

Example:

```py
list = ["a","b","c"]
print("\n- ".join(list))
```

Comment: Concatenate the added character to the front of the final product, or add it to each element and concatenate the sequence with only a newline inserted.  How are you stuck?

Comment: Asking “how are you stuck” to a pretty clear description of what I’m trying to achieve but am unable to is at the very best unhelpful and at worst passive aggressive. I understand this is a simple question but there’s nothing about it that’s unclear, and if you’re offended by simple questions there’s no need to engage at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `-`  to the start of every string with a generator comprehension then join on just `\n`:

```py
print("\n".join(f"- {x}" for x in list))
```

This code uses [f-strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). You could also just use `"- " + x` instead of `f"- {x}"`.

Answer (score 1):

You could just prepend the `-`  to the first line:

```
print('- ' + '\n- '.join(list))
```